# Property Initialization and Comparison Timing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

Context: C#, WPF, MVVM

In my viewmodels I have been using initialization logic for some of my properties that is basically a check to see if the backing property is null and, if so, initialize it. Finally, return the backing property. Here's an example for list that allows a user to select items to filter by:

```
List<CBPicklistString> _clientClassificationFilterList;
public List<CBPicklistString> ClientClassificationFilterList
{
  get
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("ClientClassificationFilterList - Get: " + _clientClassificationFilterList?.Count ?? "Null");

    if (_clientClassificationFilterList == null)
    {
      _clientClassificationFilterList = CBPicklists.PicklistStrings(CBPicklists.CLIENT_CLASSIFICATIONS).ToList();
      _clientClassificationFilterList.Insert(0, new CBPicklistString() { PicklistStringId = 0, PicklistStringValue = "(All Client Classes)" });
      SelectedClientClassificationFilter = _effectiveClientClassificationFilter = _clientClassificationFilterList[0];

      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedClientClassificationFilter");
    }

    return _clientClassificationFilterList;
  }
}
```

My method to apply the filter logic has this code:

```
if (_effectiveClientClassificationFilter != ClientClassificationFilterList[0])
    ActiveClientFilters.Add(new ActiveFilter(_effectiveClientClassificationFilter.PicklistStringValue, "ClientClassification"));
```

On the initial run, the getter should initialize the list and `_effectiveClientClassificationFilter` and the if statement should see the comparison as false (objects are equal), meaning that there is no active filter to set. But what I am seeing is that the if statement is behaving as if it sees a true (objects are not equal). When I check the values in the debugger, they are, in fact, equal. It's acting as if there is a concurrency issue where the initialization isn't finishing prior to the comparison. But this isn't a multi-threaded bit of code. Is .Net (or WPF) doing its own thing, here? Is this not a valid way to approach the list initialization? I use this logic paradigm all over the place, (and have been, for years) but this is the first time and the only place I am seeing this funky behavior. There's not a lot of other related code involved.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the data type of `_effectiveClientClassificationFilter`? Is `CBPicklistString` a class or struct and does that type override `Equals()` or the `!=`operator?

Comment: Do you also have any logic inside the `SelectedClientClassificationFilter` getter?

Comment: Are `_effectiveClientClassificationFilter`and the first element of `ClientClassificationFilterList[0]` different instances? If so, they are compared by reference and are never equal. Maybe implementing a `IEquatable(T)` for comparison can solve your problem (details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).

Comment: @LittleBit, they are the same instance. They read as the same instance, in the debugger, even though the comparison shows as not equal.

Comment: @FrankM, data types coincide. No overrides. Just checking to make sure that instances are the same.

Comment: @grek40, it's an auto-implemented property.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but i think the initial value of _effectiveClientClassificationFilter being first in the comparison is used and then the ClientClassificationFilterList is calculated changing the value of _effectiveClientClassificationFilter which i suppose it does not know. So if you reverse the order of condition, it will work correctly.

Instead of

```
if (_effectiveClientClassificationFilter != ClientClassificationFilterList[0])
```

use

```
if (ClientClassificationFilterList[0] != _effectiveClientClassificationFilter)
```